# Why cant I ping a virtual guest from host by default

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I ran into some trouble when I tried to ping my Ubuntu virtual guest from my Windows 10 host, but this [solution](https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/)  did the trick.

I'm wondering what exactly is a "host-only-adapter" and why cant the I ping the virtual machine by default? How exactly does the virtual machine access the internet when I cant ping it?

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, host-only is intended to create a new interface that is virtual and visible to the host and not in anyway connected to the physical interface that actually connects to the internet.

Itcan be thought of as a hybrid between the bridged and internal networking modes: as with bridged networking, the virtual machines can talk to each other and the host as if they were connected through a physical Ethernet switch. Similarly, as with internal networking however, a physical networking interface need not be present, and the virtual machines cannot talk to the world outside the host since they are not connected to a physical networking interface.

You might be wondering what the use-case for this would be.Think for example: one virtual machine may contain a web server and a second one a database, and since they are intended to talk to each other, the appliance can instruct VirtualBox to set up a host-only network for the two. A second (bridged) network would then connect the web server to the outside world to serve data to, but the outside world cannot connect to the database.

**How it works**

when host-only networking is used, VirtualBox creates a new software interface on the host which then appears next to your existing network interfaces. In other words, whereas with bridged networking an existing physical interface is used to attach virtual machines to, with host-only networking a new "loopback" interface is created on the host. And whereas with internal networking, the traffic between the virtual machines cannot be seen, the traffic on the "loopback" interface on the host can be intercepted.

The great thing about host-only networks is that the host itself sits on this network and so, upon proper config as in you [link](https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/) above, you can reach all the VMs.

Hope my explanation helps!

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful!  But what IP address will my router see when I access the internet from within the VM? The same as my host but using a special port?

Comment: Since I can access the Internet from the VM, I should also be able to ping the VM from the host since they are on the same network?

Comment: @Q-bertsuit yes, the host should be able to ping the VM and the VM should be able to ping the virtual interface of the host. Unless you explicitly NAT the virtual interface to the physical interface, you may not be able to ping the VM from the physical interface of the host and vice-versa (ping the physical interface of the host from the VM).

Also, regarding the IP shown on your physical router, depending on how you've done the NATting, you might see a port of the same IP of the host, but using a special port or you'd see a new IP but on the same subnet I.e physical port acts as a bridge.